# Why there is no OWD settings for Product Object

Tags: community, sharing, pricebook, partner-communities, owd

I was wondering why there is no OWD settings for Product Object. And as it was said that PriceBookEntry is a junction object for Products & ProductPortfolio then why there a OWD settings option available for PriceBook?

I am pretty confused here, because We have implemented Partner Communities in which Partner user are not able to see Products information on a report based on Custom Report type of **Opportunity with Opportunity Products** (Relationship: Opportunity with at least one Products).

Also It is said that Partner can only report on Object which are Private in OWD settings.

Thanks!
Chirag

Comment: Ironically, we had this discussion just today at work. Our use case is to allow sales to see core products, and let our integrations add products the users couldn't see, or at least could be filtered out by default. This led to a Visualforce solution.

Answer (score 1):

As this is standard salesforce behavior we really cant do anything.
You can use Profile Permissions to achieve this. :)

Answer (score 1):

OWD of Products is controlled by the PRice Book object.

Idea links for the feature request:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DysUAAS
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp8VAAS